# Accessing the NULL character of an array

Tags: c, arrays

Consider the program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "hello";

    printf("%c", *(a + 5)); 
    printf("%c", *(a + 6)); 
    printf("%c", *(a + 99));

    return 0;
}
```

Here the first printf is it printing the NULL or garbage value? What about the last two printf ?

I am confused since I am accessing outside the array bound.

Comment: `*(a+6)` and `*(a+99)` are invalid memory references.

Comment: @lurker what about *(a+5) ?

Comment: `*(a+5)` should be yielding a `0` byte, which is not a displayable character. So `printf("%c", *(a+5));` probably won't show anything. Try `printf("Value is %d\n", *(a+5));`.

Comment: `*(a+5)` is the empty cstring which contains only the `'\0'` character

Comment: There is no good reason to use `*(a + 5)` just `a[5]` is ok, and even though you can compile and execute `*(a + 6)` or `a[6]` it will cause something known as *undefined behavior*, so it's wrong.

Comment: @amdixon What is a cstring? Is it the type of `*(a + 5)`?

Comment: cstring being any `'\0'` terminated string

Comment: The character is called NUL, not NULL. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: But what is the type of `*(a + 5)`? It's not a poitner it's a single byte `a[5]`. It's true that `a + 5` (without derefernece) would be equivalent to an empty string.

Comment: type of `*(a+5)` is derived through `a => (char * ) => (a+5) => (char *) => *(a+5) => char`

Comment: @OlafSeibert It's a null character, abbreviated NUL in ASCII and other charsets.

Comment: @Jite: yes, "null character" refers to the function, but the OP wrote NULL in uppercase, which is something else (a macro with a particular function).

Answer (score 7):

When you create a character array like this

```
char a[] = "hello";
```

it is equivalent to:

```
char a[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

So your array is actually of size 6 instead of 5.  When you do

```
printf("%c",*(a+5));
```

it is okay -- printing the null terminator character is legal, although unusual. Printing a null character will usually not produce any visible output.

However, these are undefined behavior, since you are accessing characters outside the array:

```
printf("%c",*(a+6)); 
printf("%c",*(a+99));
```

With undefined behavior, there are no guarantees what will happen.  Common results are garbage or a crash.

Comment: I am confused since I cant assign *(a+5) = 'a'. Then how can I print outside the bound?

Comment: @sameer: `*(a+5) = 'a'` is legal, just unusual and error prone.  The string will no longer have a null terminator, so if you try to print `a` after doing this, you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: @sameer: I've updated my answer.  Maybe it will be clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Your array has 6 valid characters.

So `a[0]` to `a[5]` are valid access anything other than that is array out of bound access which will lead to undefined behavior

Comment: My parser fails on reading your answer's second paragraph probably because is misses any punctuation